# DataTables Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buttons' of undefined

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I am trying to take the inline editing example ([link](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple)) from the datatables.net site and make it local to my server but I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buttons' of undefined".  I have removed all code except the libraries and it still gives the error.  The editor includes are on my server and I have checked that all paths/filenames are correct.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <link href="/scripts/datatables/extensions/Editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="/scripts/datatables/extensions/Editor/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove scripts one by one to find which one is causing the issue, then debut that one.

Answer (score 0):

I had initially copied the editor.dataTables.min.css and dataTables.editor.min.js files from the example page.  I downloaded the .zip of 1.6.5 files from [here](https://editor.datatables.net/download/) and put the files on our server, updated to point to the new files and all works now.  I needed just the "JS+CSS only" files.